# LDAP Authentication Issue which failing to login Nifi UI

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi

**nifi-app.log** :

```
2019-02-07 15:24:40,475 ERROR [NiFi Web Server-22] org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider nifi.test:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: nifi.test:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
```

**nifi-user.log** :

```
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.authentication.exception.IdentityAccessException: Unable to validate the supplied credentials. Please contact the system administrator.
    at org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider.authenticate(LdapProvider.java:340)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.security.spring.LoginIdentityProviderFactoryBean$1.authenticate(LoginIdentityProviderFactoryBean.java:314)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.api.AccessResource.createAccessToken(AccessResource.java:728)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: nifi.test:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: nifi.test:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
    at org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider.authenticate(LdapProvider.java:310)
    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

**nifi.properties** :

```
# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=nifi.test
nifi.web.https.port=8090
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.jks
nifi.security.keystoreType=jks
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=vm1VrVaPN2f3xXuva03R//ZtHXoxuYc2qnZYSDpzQDQ
nifi.security.keyPasswd=vm1VrVaPN2f3xXuva03R//ZtHXoxuYc2qnZYSDpzQDQ
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=jks
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=TJbO3svNAO44hkKgXII58KZV/67sL768IBE3IaisFKs
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=ldap-provider
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=

authorizers.xml :

<authorizer>
        <identifier>file-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAuthorizer</class>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">testuser</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>

        <property name="Node Identity 1">CN=*.test,OU=Nifi</property>
    </authorizer>

login-identity-providers.xml:
<provider>
        <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
        <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>

        <property name="Manager DN">CN=testuser, OU=Nifi, DC=test,DC=local</property>
        <property name="Manager Password">pass</property>
        <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

        <property name="Referral Strategy">IGNORE</property>
        <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
        <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

        <property name="Url">ldap://nifi.test:389</property>
        <property name="User Search Base">OU=Nifi, DC=test,DC=local</property>
        <property name="User Search Filter">sAMAccountName={0}</property>

        <property name="Identity Strategy">USE_USERNAME</property>
        <property name="Authentication Expiration">2 hours</property>
</provider>
```

Need your suggests why I'm unable to get login page in Nifi?

What need to do to get user authentication with LDAP in Nifi?

Comment: Is your LDAP server running on the nifi.test host on port 389? can you connect to nifi.test:389 from other tools outside NiFi?

Comment: @BryanBende Thanks for replying.....  nmap -p 389 10.18.200.52 -                      Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-02-08 12:19 IST
Nmap scan report for nifi.ndevarajan (10.18.200.52)
Host is up (0.000078s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
389/tcp closed ldap

Comment: Try using something like Apache Studio to connect to LDAP with the same credentials. https://directory.apache.org/studio/

Comment: Also the command you showed used an IP address, but your nifi config used a hostname of nifi.test